# Java custom entity relation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, relational-database, entity-attribute-value

I have an Entity with some default fields. But I need to have ability to extend it with dynamic fields as well. That fields are related to a table (not to specific entity). I need ability to add them from admin panel (it is some sort of EAV).

So I have Entity like this

```
public class Account {

@Id
private Long id;

@Column(name = "account_name")
private String accountName;

@Column(name = "first_name")
private String firstName;

@Column(name = "last_name")
private String lastName;
//getters setters
}
```

For example, I want to extend it with new column 'salutation'.
I've created 2 tables: first for custom field names, second for appropriate values:

```
CREATE TABLE custom_fields
(
id BIGINT(20) unsigned PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
entity VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE custom_field_values
(
id BIGINT(20) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
custom_field_id BIGINT(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
entity_id BIGINT(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
value VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UQ_custom_value ON custom_field_values(custom_field_id, entity_id);
```

Now I need some relation on Account entity, to obtain Map of customFieldName=>customFieldValue. Is it possible to create relation only by where clause, like

```
SELECT name FROM custom_fields WHERE entity = "account"
```

for map key, and for values

```
SELECT value FROM custom_field_values INNER JOIN custom_fields ON custom_fields.id = custom_field_values.custom_field_id WHERE entity_id = :id
```

Is it possible? I need to provide ability to create this columns from admin panel, and ability to fill previously created custom fields for users.

Thanks!

Comment: You want to add a column in runtime to your entity then add data to it ?

Comment: Yes, but it has to store it in DB

Comment: Actually i didn't go through something like that before, but even you allowed to do that what you will do if server down for any reason, you will loose controlling on new columns so in next restart of server the columns you created in runtime you will not have any control on it, so you should not do something like that or your will be the big looser finally

Comment: Why should I loose them? The columns as well as appropriate values are stored in DB. But db structure is knows as "vertical" db (the data is a composition from two tables)

Comment: After restarting server for any reason, can you tell me how u can know new columns from JPA entity which physically not exist as properties in JPA java entity but just exist in database ?